# Google Language Translator overrides the style

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am creating a website using wordpress and I just integrate Google language translator .  Everything works fine but the problem is that when I translate language it changes the font size .  So by default (without translating) I am getting

```
<h1 class="intro-text">iDEAS , Solutions , Strategies for your Business <br>
</h1>
```

from the inspect element . But when I translate it to Spanish or any other languages it reduce the size . I inspect in the Inspect element and I am getting

```
<h1 class="intro-text">
<font><font>ideas, soluciones, estrategias para su negocio </font></font>
<br> </h1>
```

. That is why the problem occurs how to over come this . If I translate I need a result like ,

```
<h1 class="intro-text">
ideas, soluciones, estrategias para su negocio 
<br> </h1>
```

any help will be really appreciated .

Comment: You can write `CSS` for those `font` tags only when they appear inside `class="intro-text"`.

Comment: Could you give me an example . I am not very sure how to do that

Comment: Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/s22276a1/1/

Comment: Thanks , I will check it

Comment: Thanks vivekkupadhyay it worked perfectly

Comment: Okay @Vishnu , then I can post it as an answer :)

Comment: Yes , it will help somebody atleast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want same `font-size` even when you `translate` the page, then you should write `CSS` for `font` tags which are being appended while the `translation` within `class="intro-text"`.

```
<!-- Bofore Translation -->
<h1 class="intro-text">
   iDEAS , Solutions , Strategies for your Business <br>
</h1>
<!-- After Translation -->
<h1 class="intro-text">
   <font><font>ideas, soluciones, estrategias para su negocio </font></font><br>
</h1>
```

`CSS`:

```
.intro-text,
.intro-text font { font-size:20px;}
```

This will maintain the same `font-size` after the `translation`.